# Fit VAR model with unknown order in Matlab

Tags: time-series, estimation, matlab, vector-autoregression

I have a multivariate observed time series $Y_t$ and I want to find the best fitting VAR process for it.

I have the econometric toolbox in Matlab and can use 'vgxvarx' if I pre-specify an order for the VAR process. However I want the order of the process to be estimated as well. Is there a function to do this in Matlab?

Comment: How much data you have? How many dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic order selection. You can run many different orders in the loop and compare fit statistics to choose the best order.

I would also run cross correlation for all variable pairs to get an idea of lead/lag relationships. ACF/PACF also helps to get an intuition on lag structure of the series themselves.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some ways to do it (including p in the likelihood) but you are no more taking the advantage of VAR model (whis is a simple MLE).

I would suggest:

- plot the acf of your time series, you will have an idea of p.
- Estimate the VAR with p-1,p,p+1, and see if there is significant changes between coefficients.